# Group Action for Lens Space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let the lens space $L(p,q)$ be $S^3/\mathbb{Z}_p$ where the supposed 'group action' of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ on $S^3$ is given by:
$(z_1,z_2) \rightarrow ( \rho z_1, \rho^q z_2) $ where $\rho = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$, where we have $(p,q) = 1$. But a group action is a map $\mathbb{Z}_p \times S^3 \rightarrow S^3$? So what is the value of $g \cdot (z_1, z_2)$ when $g \neq q$?

Is the group action a constant map wrt the group element? In this case, the orbit of an element consists of exactly one element, and also equivalence classes (i.e. an element of $S^3/\mathbb{Z}_p$) are singleton sets as different points on $S^3$ would rotate to different points, correct?

Comment: What's written is the action of the generator $g$ of $Z_p$. From this, try to figure out how $g^k$ acts for $k\in [1, p]$.

Comment: Oh I get it now, thank you.